# Where can I find the TypeScript source code of the SharePoint Framework?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

Where can I find the TypeScript source code of the SharePoint Framework?

With Microsoft being more open and generally providing everything as open source nowadays I expected to find it pretty quickly. But Google betrays me.

Can somebody help me out and point me to a repository (GitHub?)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SPFX source code is not open source at this point.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/74280)

Comment: Not sure I follow.  The answer to the question "where can I find the source code" is "You can't, the source code is not open source".